# Can we write down a formula for the simultaneous images of the $C_q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, twin-primes

Fix $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Define $C_2(x) = 2x, \ C_3(x) = 3x$, $C_5(x) = 2 [\frac{x + 2}{3}] + [\frac{ x + 1}{3}] + 2 [ \frac{x}{3}]$, more generally for prime $p_n \geq q \geq 5$ define $C_q(x) = 2[\frac{ x + q - 3}{q - 2}] + [\frac{x + q - 2}{q - 2}] + \dots + [\frac{ x + 1}{q-2}] + 2[\frac{x}{q-2}]$.

If the least non-negative $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $x = C_2(x_2) = C_3(x_3) = \dots =C_q(x_q)$ for some $x_i \in \Bbb{Z}$; is less than $p_{n+1}^2 - 1$, then $x$ is a twin prime average.

So the goal might be to show that for each $n \geq 1$ such a small enough $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ exists as a common image point of all the $C_i$.

Have you seen this form of the twin prime conjecture before?

The opposite of the twin prime conjecture would be that for none but finitely many $n \geq 1$ can you find such a solution.

---

According to [Wikipedia (Quotients with Floor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients) we actually have an even more simpler (algebraic) form, because for $q \geq 5$ we have that each

$$
C_q(x) = x + [\frac{ x + q - 3}{q - 2}] + [\frac{x}{q - 2}]
$$

The majority of the summation collapses down to $x$ according to the Wikipedia article.

---

**Question.**

Can we write down a formula for the simultaneous images of the $C_q$?  Note that this of course allows you to temporarily ignore the $\lt p_{n+1}^2 - 1$ bound.

Thanks.

Comment: I could derive this for you if interested, but the derivation isn't as interesting as the form itself as presented.

Comment: Interestingly, according to this a few paragraphs down:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients

We can simplify the involved expressions even further!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @An_Elephant I did it. I edited the post.  :D    I'm wondering if we can now say that the floors will each increment by $1$ at a certain rate so that etc.

Comment: I've changed your title to attempt to be informative about what you're really asking. Please choose a different title if this one is not suitable, which is informative and avoids blog-post-like titles.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?  I thought of evaluating the $q = 5$ one on 3 different branches one for each residue moduo $q - 2 = 3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first assume we're at step (in some hypothetical proof) $n = 3$ so that $q = 5$ and we want:

$$
6x = C_5(y) = y + [\frac{y + q - 3}{q-2}] + [\frac{y}{q-2}]
$$

well after some thought, let's break this up into cases modulo $y \pmod{q-2}$:

$$
C_5(3y) = 5y \\
C_5(3y + 1) = 5y + 2 \\
C_5(3y + 2) = 5y + 3 \\
$$

I'll do the last one:

$$
C_5(3y + 2) = 3y + 2 + [\frac{3y + 2 + q - 3}{3}] + [\frac{3y + 2}{3}] = \\ 3y + 2 + y + 1 + y = 5y + 3 \ \blacksquare
$$

So working the case $y' = 3y + i$ for $0 \leq i \lt 3$ we have that:

$$
6 x = C_5(y') \iff 6x -5y  =  i + [i\gt 0] = c
$$

where $[i \gt 0] = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } i \gt 0 \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.

The general solutions to the linear diophantine equation  for a given $i$ are:
$$
x = c +5k,\ y=c+6k
$$

Thus the twin prime average solutions would be $6x = 6(c + 5k) \lt p_{4}^2 - 1$:

Or whenever:

$$
\frac{\frac{p_4^2 - 1}{6} - c}{5} \gt 1
$$

Comment: In fact there are exactly $3 + \sum_{c =0,2,3}[\frac{\frac{p_4^2 - 1}{6} - c}{5}]$.  In particular there are at least the solutions $a = 6(c + 5\cdot 0)$ for $c = 0, 2,3$.  Since setting $k = 0$ will always satisfy the inequality $6(c + 5k) \lt 48$, for  $c = 0,2,3$.  This makes me think that in general a continued fraction may be involved.